# Determine how much data to read from UART using matlab

Tags: matlab, protocols, uart, serial-communication

I'm currently working on fething data out from my uart line; 
I have a PSoC 4 hooked up with uart, which is sending just fine (all the time, with 20ms delay between each data), then i have matlab to receive the data.

I'm using the `fscanf(s, '%d')` function is and it returns about 3 numbers send by the uart, example down below:

```
s = serial('COM3'); %assigns the object s to serial port

set(s, 'InputBufferSize', 1024); %number of bytes in inout buffer
set(s, 'FlowControl', 'hardware');
set(s, 'BaudRate', 115200);
set(s, 'Parity', 'none');
set(s, 'DataBits', 8);
set(s, 'StopBit', 1);
set(s, 'Timeout',0.5);
%clc;

disp(get(s,'Name'));
prop(1)=(get(s,'BaudRate'));
prop(2)=(get(s,'DataBits'));
prop(3)=(get(s, 'StopBit'));
prop(4)=(get(s, 'InputBufferSize'));

disp(['Port Setup Done!!',num2str(prop)]);

         %opens the serial port
disp('Running');
fopen(s);
b = fscanf(s, '%d') 

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Matlab terminal:
b  = 
-213
-205
-215
```

The program fetches 3 numbers where i'd like to only fetch the first one (-213)
Btw the number can be anything between 16000 and - 16000

Best regards

Comment: Can you please add part of transmiter code (C code I guess)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using fscanf, you could use fread to read a specific number of bytes.

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/serial.fread.html

In your case where s = serial('COM3'), to read in one byte you would write:

```
b = fread(s, 1, 'uchar');
```

where the arguments are:   obj, size, 'precision'

P.s. Don't forget to `fclose(s)` the serial port when you're finished so you can run the program again without getting the "Obj has already been opened" error :)

All the best..